How parse json value into array with jq
I have this
{ "1": { "Split": { "result": "first_image" } }, "2": { "Split": { "result": "second_image" } } }
I tried .[].Split.result but it gives be below result;
"first_image"
"second_image"
but I want below output
I want the below output
["first_image","second_image"]

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Collect the results you get into an array by wrapping your filter inside array brackets:
jq -c '[.[] | .Split.result]'

Demo
Note that for filters of the form [.[] | …] there's a shorthand function map(…), so this is equivalent to the above:
jq -c 'map(.Split.result)'

Demo
Alternatively, if you just wanted to collect all scalars into an array, traverse the document with .. and collect the results as before:
jq -c '[..|scalars]'

Demo
For the given input, all of these produce (with the -c flag compacted into a single line):
["first_image","second_image"]

